# Linux bridge interface not showing or receiving arp response

Tags: linux, networking

I have a linux bridge named mybridge set up on an Ubuntu machine. It has interfaces ens38 and ens39 attached. A node with IP 192.168.4.90(Lets call it A) need to send packets to another node 192.168.4.80(Lets call it B).

A is connected to ens38 and B is connected to ens39. In the linux bridge using wireshark, I can see the messages from the mac address of A, asking

```
who has 192.168.4.80, tell 192.168.4.90.
```

In node B, I see the same message coming in and its arp response towards the linux bridge. But in the linux bridge, I do not see that message coming on the ens39 interface.

Comment: Is the problem that you don't see your ARP response in wireshark or that A never receives the ARP response from B?

Comment: My problem was solved by this http://backreference.org/2010/07/28/linux-bridge-mac-addresses-and-dynamic-ports/    . My bridge was taking the mac address of the the first interface. This interface was used for traffic routing.

Comment: @AshishKurian Thanks for the tip! In my case the bridge had gotten a random MAC, when I set it to eth0's MAC (my upstrem) everything started working again.